# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'angularJSCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code. Because I don't see anything missed.  It was all working during the class. I'm quite new to javascript and angular.

I tried to check other threads with the same error but didn't help me to solve the issue.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularJS"> 
<head>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    {{"Type your name"}}

    <div ng-controller="angularJSCtrl as kontrol">

        <button ng-click ="kontrol.sayHello()"> Click here </button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="kontrol.name">
        <h3> All students list </h3>

        <div ng-repeat="el in kontrol.studentObj">
            <div ng-show="{{ el.age < 20 }}"> {{el}}</div>
        </div>

        <includer></includer>
        <br>
        {{ kontrol.price | currency}}
        <br>
        {{ kontrol.date | date}}

    </div>
```

controller.js

```
        (function () {
            angular.module("angularJS")
            .controller("angularJSCtrl", angularJSMethod);
            .directive("directCtrl", directMethod);

            function angularJSMethod(){
                var vm = this;
                vm.sayHello = sayHello;
                vm.name = "Orkun";
                vm.studentNames = ['John', 'Robbert', 'Adam'];
                vm.studentObj = [{name: 'Orkun', age: 22}, {name: 'Bob', age: 18}];
                vm.price = 2000;
                vm.date = new Date();

            function sayHello(){
                alert("Welcome" + ' ' + vm.name)
            }}

            function directMethod(){
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl: 'custom.html'
                }
            }

        })();
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    angular.module("angularJS", []);

})();
```

Comment: in your html you declare the `as` as `kontrol` but in your controller you declare the `as` as vm. Your html should be `vm` as well. `ng-controller="angularJSCtrl as vm"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the  problem is that you don't need `semicolon`:

```
    .controller("angularJSCtrl", angularJSMethod); <--- here
    .directive("directCtrl", directMethod);
```

Remove it and everything will work fine